# Easy Frontend/GUI for Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have seen a few solutions to this, but I want to know what the absolute best front-end solution is for my application. I'm making a basic web app, that needs a front end capable of taking in input and storing it, then display it later. I need an easy to learn a solution that works with Python 3, I have tried tkinter but that was a little confusing, and most of the documentation is for Python 2, I have also seen Flask and Django, but I'm not 100% sure what exactly they are. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "absolute best front-end", the choice depends entirely on what you're trying to achieve. First and foremost you should do more reading; *tkinter* is certainly not a web development framework. Flask and Django are. If you're not sure what they do, then again there's some reading ahead of you.

My recommendation would be to go with Flask, as it's relatively nice & easy. Plus, deployment of Flask apps is made quite easy with popular cloud providers.

You might want to check out [Dash](https://plot.ly/products/dash/), as it makes development of analytical web applications exceptionally easy. Is it the best? All depends on your application. Again, there's no "best" - there's just a good fit. I can tell you Django isn't (yet!) for you.